# Microsoft Visual C++, Visual Studio, How to fix the error: identifier "GetAsyncKeyState" is undefined

Tags: c++, winapi, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I am new to C++, directX and Windows programming.

Here are the header files that I am referencing, and namespaces that I am using:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Common/DirectXHelper.h"
using namespace Windows;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
using namespace Windows::UI::Core;
using namespace std;
```

Here is the line that causes the error:

```
return (GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000 != 0);
```

I do not know if I misspelled something or if it is a compiler issue, I have checked everywhere and have not found the solution.

I have also tried using the GetCursorPos method and it did not work.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
The error message is:

error C3861: "GetAsyncKeyState": identifier not found

key is an int that has the key code of the key I am testing

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the **exact** error message you're getting.

Comment: @Josh What is `key`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presence of `namespace Windows::UI::Core` suggests that you are working on UWP application while `::GetAsyncKeyState` is only available for "desktop" applications [as stated at **Requirements** documentation section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx). For UWP applications you can utilize [`CoreWindow::GetAsyncKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.corewindow#Windows_UI_Core_CoreWindow_GetAsyncKeyState_Windows_System_VirtualKey_).